# Why is my AWS EKS cluster not running properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-auto-scaling

I setup my AWS EKS cluster by using on-demand(5 instances) and spot instances(Auto-scaled 27 desired instances).I configured auto-scaling pod to ensure the nodes will be created when scale up is triggered.At first the cluster works fine but after sometime the spot instances with the running pods state turn to pending and cluster is scaling down for no reason(to 15 nodes e.g).Then my services are unreachable. In the logs at AWS I see that spot node group is degraded and the error is "Could not launch Spot Instances. UnfulfillableCapacity - Unable to fulfill capacity due to your request configuration. Please adjust your request and try again. Launching EC2 instance failed." After sometime it works normally and pods are scaled up but for 40 mins the services are unreachable. I don't think this would happen if I use all on-demand instances but what is causing this error with spot instances can someone please explain ? I can give further information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Spot instances are interruptible; they can be reclaimed when that capacity is needed elsewhere. If you have workloads that are not tolerant of interruptions, you shouldn't use Spot or you should run at least 1 replica on an on-demand instance. The easiest way to avoid insufficient capacity errors is by *diversifying the instances types* in your ASG and/or Karpenter provisioner. Please review https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/cluster-autoscaling/ and https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/karpenter/ for further information.